# how to grep only text preceded by several ‘=’ characters

Tags: grep

I want to grep only text preceded by several ‘=’ characters.
tried this but doesn't work

```
cat sometext.txt | grep \=
```

and

```
cat sometext.txt | grep ^--[[:alpha:]]\{2,\}=[^=]\+$
```

(where sometext.txt is just a file containing lots of text, including equal signs)

but none of them work

Comment: (1) What is the filename ? Here , "sometext./txt" looks odd ? (2) What do you mean by "not work" ? (3) What does the file contain ? (4) What is the output you get ? (5) What output do you want ? (6) What is the complicated regex ? Where did you get that ? [[ these are not idle questions , the "clarifying" answers to these may help you get a Solution ]]

Comment: Is it always the same number of '=' ? and you tried ```grep ^===``` ? I agree that we need some sample/example of text you're working with

Comment: It may be that, based on my Previous Comment, OP figured out that there was a "/" in the filename & rectified it. Otherwise, the clarifying queries ( & responses ) will help in figuring things out. @Smock

Comment: edited the comment, thanks!

Comment: You could cat sometext.txt | tr '=' '\n' | grep "yourtext"

Answer (score 0):

```
grep '^=\+.\+$ file
```

will return each lines that begin with 1 or more `=`

If your OS support it, you can do:

```
grep -oP '^=+\K.+$' file
```

this will print only the text after the `=`